# QLineEdit: How to prevent user from entering asterisk (*)?

Tags: regex, qt, qlineedit, qvalidator

I'm using QLineEdit in my application. I want to prevent the user from entering '*' anywhere in the text. I tried to QRegExpValidator but could not able to set the proper regexp. Please help.

Comment: *could not able to set the proper regexp* - What regex did you try?

Comment: Do you have any code to share, with what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!

```
QRegExp re("[^*]+");
QRegExpValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(re, this);
```

setting this validator to QLineEdit did the job!